# How to generate One XML element with value multiple time using JAXB While having For loop?

Tags: java, jaxb

**Model class the property define like::**

```
@XmlElement(name = "GEOMETRY")
protected List<String> geometrytype; 
public List<String> getGEOMETRYTYPE() {

    if (geometrytype == null) {
        geometrytype = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return this.geometrytype;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the remarks property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setGEOMETRYTYPE(List<String> value) {
    this.geometrytype = value;
}
```

**Now call this Model to .java class**

```
ArrayList<Coordinate> cord= l.getLinkPointList();

for(int j=0;j<cord.size();j++){ 
   xml_node.getGEOMETRYTYPE().add("X=\""+ cord.get(j).x+ "\"Y=\""+cord.get(j).y+ "\"");
}
```

> Any other option but only with jaxb

Answer (score 0):

Use your marshaller to do the work.
Maybe try this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClass.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(pojo, System.out);
```